# Vertically align an image tag in a div with less height in responsive fluid design

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I've read articles and solutions here about centering elements while I'm trying to **fit** and **vertically center** an image to a div with less height than the image.

I used to depend on background-image but now I'm searching for a solution to use the *image tag with unknown height* which can be used safely with responsive design and vertically align the image so the larger parts than the div go outside (top and bottom).

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

(worked but not sure why there are some differences with some browsers)

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="img-container">
      <div class="img-helper">
         <img src="/media/projects/cats/large/cats_0001.jpg"></img>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-container {
   height:260px;
   position:relative;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}
.img-helper {
    position: absolute;
    top: -25%;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    height:260px;
    width:100%;
}
.img-helper img {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

## Here's a screenshot clarify how I need to handle my image :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE1p5.png

Update:

I've added this piece of jQuery and worked with few updates in CSS.

So my question: is there a way to do this without jQuery using CSS only?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.img-helper>img').each(function () {
    var imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    var divHeight = $(this).parent().innerHeight();
        if (imgHeight > divHeight) {
            $(this).css({ 'top' : "-" + ((imgHeight - divHeight )/2) + "px" });
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().css({ 'height' : imgHeight + "px" });
        };
    });
});
=============
CSS
=============
.img-container{
   position:relative;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.img-helper {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    height:260px;
    width:100%;
}
.img-helper img {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Heh, I worked on this a few months ago and can tell you a lot of things that don't work... Ultimately, I wound up using javascript and relative positioning...

Comment: Try making it a background-image and using `background-size: cover;`

Comment: thank you both, @philwills: I have changed the positioning use but used a jQuery which want to avoid.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Saucier: yes, I used to used the background solutions but for some reasons and for print compatibility need an image tag :)

Comment: @hsobhy Background images should print fine...

Comment: @ZachSaucier only when print backgrounds is enabled... usually not by default...